Freetype missing - CMake on Windows
I have been through all the posts I could find on here about this but nothing works.
I am trying to build a project using CMake on Windows using Visual Studio Code.
I have installed,

VS with C/C++ & CMake extensions
msys64, added ucrt root to PATH
vcpkg
used msys-MinGW64 to install Freetype pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype
added ucrt/include to PATH

I go into my build folder and enter cmake .. & off it goes until it throwsn the following error,
-- Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY) (found version "2.13.2")
CMake Error at dependencies/ImGuiApp/dependencies/imgui-1.90.6-docking/CMakeLists.txt:222 (message):
  IMGUI_ENABLE_FREETYPE but FreeType was not found.

I have included every folder that mentions it in my PATH but still it cant be found by CMake.
Anyone any clue why the Freetype library cant be found?

"added ucrt/include to PATH" - this is unnecessary. Your problem is What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?. You're using UCRT64 environment, but the freetype package you've downloaded is for MINGW64, not UCRT64.
